# Symantec End Point Protection

Tags: security, anti-virus, symantec

We are planning a mass rollout of Symantec Endpoint protection. We currently have Symantec antivirus version 10 running on the systems. From testing the roll out works fine but it does not take affect until after a reboot. The questions I have are:

1. Is there any way to make the software run and initiate without the machines needing a reboot.
2. If a reboot is needed will my clients be unprotected until the reboot finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1- are you going to do a migration from SAV 10?
Question 2- Yes you need to reboot for the new drivers loaded, especially if you enabled certain features such as app and device control.

Comment: Yes we are planning to migrate from SAV 10, I thought I would have to perform a reboot, was just trying to see if I could make it easier on the end user.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: +1 As redknight mentioned, the reboot applies to certain features. AV seems to be active after install. You could also push out the client at end of day and force a reboot. This would solve the issue and is simple to do from the SEPM.